# Wifilink 5100 AGN mass update

Tags: wifi, windows-registry, nic, intel

We are using a Meru enterprise wireless network with 180 APs. Recently, many users connections are dropping frequently. After much troubleshooting, we have determined much of the trouble is due to some settings in the advanced properties of the wireless nic on our notebooks.

Now we want to send out the changes in a Zenworks bundle, but I cannot find these settings in the registry or anywhere we might be able to send out as a remote package.

Does anyone know where to find these settings for an Intel wifilink 5100 card other that the NIC properties itself? We really do not want to manually configure 600 notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where those settings are but when i was working with Zenworks a long time ago (we were using version 3 if that is any indication). There was a utility that came with it that you ran before an install and then after an install and it would capture the configuration changes. If something like that still exists you might be able to use that to create your package.